# NSDataDetector phone numbers

Tags: ios, regex, phone-number

I am using NSDataDetector to parse a text and retrieve the numbers. Here is my code:

```
 NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
 error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:locationAndTitle options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[locationAndTitle length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {


        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) {

            self.theNumber = [match phoneNumber];
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it sometime returns something like this:

Telephone: 9729957777
OR
9729957777x3547634

I don't want that to appear and to remove it would be harder then using a regex code to retrieve the numbers. Do you have any idea on how to retrieve only the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would just use `-substringWithRange:` on the string to remove everything past and including the 'x' character:

```
NSString * myPhoneNum = @"9729957777x3547634";
NSRange r = [myPhoneNum rangeOfString:@"x"];
if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
    myPhoneNum = [myPhoneNum substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, r.location)];
}
NSLog(@"Fixed number: %@", myPhoneNum);
```

Any idea where the x3547634 comes from, anyway?